# What is the best practice for e-mail by javascript?

Tags: javascript, macos, safari

I'm sending e-mail from a html form/text field. But OSX Safari does not import the main text into the email client like chrome does. What is the best practice for what I want to do, and how can I solve the compatability issue?

This is the method I've used:

```js
function sendMail() {
  var link = "mailto:postto@myself.com" +
    "?cc=" +
    "&subject=" + escape("Inquiry via website") +
    "&body=" + escape(document.getElementById('input2000').value);

  window.location.href = link;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input2000" name="message" placeholder="Write a message here."></textarea>

<button type="button" id="formBtn" onclick="sendMail(); return false">
```

I want to click the button and fully fill out an email in the users preferred client.

Comment: `escape()` is deprecated, use `encodeURIComponent()`.

Comment: I just tried it in Safari on MacOS High Sierra, and the body was imported into the email.

Comment: Best way is to send an email yourself from your server instead of trying to open the email client

Comment: Sometime Safari won't do it - maybe because of the deprecated method?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments! Please also chip in your viewpoints of this method. There are pros and cons to choosing this above mailing by server, or just using a traditional html mailto. I find it's good to get the user typing without leaving the browser, and then leaving just one click to ship the e-mail of in the end.